# How can I combine comma format with scientific format in SAS?

Tags: format, sas, image

I have data that I would like to represent as `comma10.2` when less than 1,000,000 and `e10.` when greater than or equal to 1,000,000.  It seems like there might be a way to do this using the picture format, so I thought I might also making missing values show up as `--`.  This is what I've got so far:

```
proc format;
  picture DashMiss . = '--' (noedit)
                   low - <1000000 = "000,009.99"
                   1000000 - high = ????;
run;
```

I'm not sure how to represent scientific notation using picture (hence the question marks).  I don't have to just use `picture` if there's an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to use brackets to add the conditional format:

```
proc format;
  picture DashMiss . = '--' (noedit)
                   low - <1000000 = "000,009.99"
                   1000000 - high = [e10.];
run;
```

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly how I'd do it.  I don't think you can do it with anything other than picture.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to mark your answer as complete once you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could've simply used  the best6. format or bestd6.2 to achieve the same results. It naturally uses scientific notation whenever the length is beyond the first of the 2 integers.

Comment: The problem is that it does not naturally use commas.